# How to use MQTT concept in FLASK REST API?

Tags: python, flask, mqtt, paho

I have a requirement where will have a POST api call ,read the json data from this and publish the messages to this topic "/home/floor_1/room" before publishing need to connect to the broker also and then return a success response .
Project structure:

```
│   app.py
│   config.py
│   Dockerfile
│   requirement.txt
│
├───app_services
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───controller
│   │   │   send_down_link.py
│   │   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───models
│   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │
│   │   ├───database
│   │   │   │   device.py
```

In app.py

```
from app_services import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=app.config['HOST'], port=app.config['PORT'], debug=app.config['DEBUG'])
```

in app_service/**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_mqtt import Mqtt
from app_service.controller.send_down_link import SendDownlink

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
mqtt = Mqtt(app)
api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(SendDownlink, "/api/t1/device/")
```

In controller/send_down_link.py:

```
class SendDownlink(Resource):
       def post(self):
         input_data =  request.get_json()
         message = input_data['message']
```

I want to publish this message to "/home/floor_1/room" topic . So i just want accommodate mqtt code in this 'post' method. Dont know how to work around it . Any suggestion ?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I have tired in a single script using paho-mqtt , so running a single file and connect to broker or publishing a message or subscribing a topic is easy but dont know how to work with flask and mqtt. Going through this [link]https://flask-mqtt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#connect-to-a-broker but not getting how to connect to broker and where to write this all mqtt concept code in the api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your stated goal is to just publish a message then the simplest way is to use the shortcut method provided by the Paho library that will handle all the connection and publication in a single call.

https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#publish-single-example

e.g.

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

publish.single("home/floor_1/room", "payload", hostname="mqtt.eclipse.org")
```

p.s. Topics really shouldn't start with a leading `/`, it adds an unneeded `null` to the start of the topic tree and breaks things like Shared Subscriptions when you try and scale things later.

Comment: Yeah ,its not just about publishing  but where do i connect to broker and all the callbacks where do i need to declare ? All this required before a client publishing something.

Comment: Your question explicitly says it's just about publishing a message. If that is not the case edit the question.

Comment: That edit hasn't changed anything. The option I have suggested has removed all the need to connect before trying to publish.

Comment: I have tired the above suggestion , its working but here i cant see any logs from mqtt . Is there any other way where  i can see the logs and connecting to the broker and publish the message . Anyway thanks a lot .